# How to throw exception when the destination folder does not exist in python

Tags: python, copy, except, shutil

I am working on classification of files based on a criteria, So I may not know the destination folder names until the runtime. Since it involves large number of files, I dont want to check each time before copying whether the destination folder exists or not. I am thinking of a mechanism like this,

```
try:
    shutil.copy(srcfile , dstdir)
except:
    os.makedir(dstdir)
    shutil.copy(srcfile , dstdir)
```

The problem here is that instead of throwing exception , it is copied as a file with the folder name.
Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: You are passing the destination directory *as the name for the file copy*; add the file name to the end, too.

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize **if** and **else** to do the same task,the code is given below:

```
    path = os.getcwd() + pathRelative
    dstdir= os.path.dirname(path)
    if not os.path.exists(dstdir):
        os.makedirs(d)
        shutil.copy(srcfile , dstdir)
    else:
       shutil.copy(srcfile , dstdir)
```